# python iterate over 2 lists then assign longer lists to shorter lists

Tags: python

I have two arrays different length.
One array of user information
Second array of dictinaries of proxy information.
I have 50 differnet proxy and 100 different accounts.
They're both an array of dictionaries.

Below is what proxy array looks like:

```
[
    {
        "username": "", 
        "ip": "", 
        "password": "", 
        "port": "",
        "accounts":[] ## this is where I store 2 accounts.
    }
]
```

And below is what user array looks like:

```
[
    {
        "username": "", 
        "first_name": "", 
        "password": "", 
        "email": "", 
        "proxy": ""
    }
]
```

MY GOAL:
I want to iterate over 50 different proxies then append 2 account to each proxies.
So my output would be something like

```
[
    {
        "username": "", 
        "ip": "", 
        "password": "", 
        "port": "",
        "accounts":[] ## this is where I store 2 accounts.
    }
]
```

I want to assign my 50 proxies 2 accounts per proxy.

This is what I've tried so far and miserably failed.

```
proxyData = proxyData() # 50 proxy list
userData = userData() # 100 user list.
proxy_len = len(userData)


idx = 1
for proxy in proxyData:
    proxy['users'] = userData[idx - 1], userData[idx]
    idx = (idx + 1) % proxy_len
    print idx
```

The following code produces tons of same proxy for all my users; I want 2 proxy for each user.

The error I'm currently having is; the iteration seems to be wrong and gives me this output.

```
[
    {
        "username": "", 
        "ip": "", 
        "password": "", 
        "port": "", 
        "accounts": [
            {
                "username": "name8338614", 
                "first_name": "Name", 
                "password": "41asdasdasd", 
                "email": "name83384@gmail.com", 
                "proxy": ""
            }, 
            {
                "username": "smith83213334", 
                "first_name": "Smith", 
                "password": "4108605ciplov", 
                "email": "smith83213334@gmail.com", 
                "proxy": ""
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "username": "laurenburn7800", 
        "ip": "104.160.233.44", 
        "password": "f61h66jyu2", 
        "port": "21265", 
        "users": [
            {
                "username": "smith83213334", 
                "first_name": "Smith", 
                "password": "4108605ciplov", 
                "email": "smith83213334@gmail.com", 
                "proxy": ""
            }, 
            {
                "username": "johnson111765968", 
                "first_name": "Johnson", 
                "password": "4108605Diplov", 
                "email": "johnson111765968@gmail.com", 
                "proxy": ""
            }
        ]
    }, 
]
```

You see how smith83213334 user is iterated twice; it shouldn't. Each accounts should only be iterated ONCE. In this case the user johnson111765968 should've been on smith83213334 place instead.

Comment: Do you mean 
proxy['accounts'] = user
Now?

Comment: Yep! I updated the thread to show you what I've tried so far, I tweked your code. However it seems to iterate wrong now. I'll post output too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the account as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) since you know there would be two values.
This can be achieved by [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and `range`. `zip` would produce an iterable that would end once the shorter of the two ranges is exhausted.

```
   for proxy,idx in zip(proxyData, range(0,len(userData), 2)):
       user1, user2 = userData[idx], userData[idx + 1]
       proxy['account'] = user1, user2
```

Comment: It looks like it's setting the same proxy 4 times. I have userData total length of 100. Each accounts should have 2 proxies.

Comment: Each account should have 2 proxies, for 100 accounts that means you have 100*2=200 proxies. You have 50 proxies. So each will have to be used 200/50=4 times.

Comment: Shoot! I'm thinking wrong. I'll refactor my entire question. It was more like assign each proxies with 2 accounts

Comment: Refactored my question!

Comment: The answer iterates accounts twice. Ive shown the error output on the main thread please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Also using set gives me this TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: I have updated the answer. You dont need % since loength of user array would always be greater .